# How to dynamically modify editor title menu bar from script in VSCode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to dynamically add and remove [editor title menu options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesmenus)(**...** menu on top right side) whenever a new file is opened or closed in editor?

I know I can add it to package.json but don't know how to do this at runtime via JS/TS.

```
"contributes": {
    "menus": {
        "editor/title": [{
            "command": "workbench.openthisfile",
                "group": "workbench"
        }]
    }
}
```

---

Basically, I want to show a list of currently opened files in the editor title menu. And clicking on a file name would open it in editor.
  Behaviour is similar to Visual Studio

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So I followed a different approach where user can enable/disable the menu bar actions from extension settings:

```
"contributes": {
        "configuration": [
            {
                "title": "Shortcut Menu Bar configuration",
                "properties": {
                    "Save active file": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false, // user can enable/disable icon
                        "description": "show icon for save active file"
                    },
                    ....
```

And I executed below command on menu bar icon click to show list of opened files:

```
commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup').then(function () {
        });
```